# while using Google chart setOnLoadCallback is not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

While calling this function i am getting a blank page with no body. I did some testing and found that alert() does not trigger. any suggessions?

```
function draw()
  {

   google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

   google.setOnLoadCallback(function (){

      alert("callback");
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'header');
      data.addColumn('number', 'percntile');
      data.addRows([
       ['above', 50.1],
       ['below', 49.9]
      ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'tfyfty',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300
               };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#content'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling you `draw` function? Are you including google script? The only error I see is using

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#content'));
```

Instead of :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('content'));
```

Works fine for me changing that: http://jsfiddle.net/kpv5nr30/

Answer (score 0):

I think May be your function calling is not right for this Try to put alert on first line of draw().if it is work then there must be any syntax error.....Try the load method calling as   ... `google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });`

Answer (score 0):

The google loader behaves strangely when called from inside other functions.  If you set the callback inline with the loader, you should not have any problems:

```
function draw()
{
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: function () {
        alert("callback");
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'header');
        data.addColumn('number', 'percntile');
        data.addRows([
            ['above', 50.1],
            ['below', 49.9]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            'title':'tfyfty',
            'width':400,
            'height':300
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#content'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }});
}
```